# Does mysql profiling tool can work to monitor a different connection?

Tags: mysql, profiling

MySQL 5 comes with a profiling tool that I can enable using "set profiling = 1", the problem is that one connection cannot monitor "queries" from another connection. Is there a way to enable that?

```
mysql> set profiling=1;
mysql> show profiles;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can profile your queries by modifying your wrapper functions and logging the queries.

With MySQL 5 you can turn on slow query logging if you wish.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html